# decode the filename of a DirectoryEntry returned by window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL with content://

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

I'm trying to retrieve the local path of a `content://` URI provided by Google Drive using the `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL` function.

Here is the incoming intent object:

```
{
  "action": "android.intent.action.SEND",
  "extras": {
    "android.intent.extra.STREAM": "content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3DfhNPFErrgrEv9o4Q0EfWItmhwQRdSI8diNatIJQGsbDn8UOC%0A"
  },
  "clipItems": [
    {
      "uri": "content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3DfhNPFErrgrEv9o4Q0EfWItmhwQRdSI8diNatIJQGsbDn8UOC%0A",
      "type": "image/jpeg",
      "extension": "jpg"
    }
  ],
  "type": "image/jpeg",
  "flags": 453509121,
  "component": "ComponentInfo{io.cozy.drive.mobile/io.cozy.drive.mobile.MainActivity}"
}
```

`window.resolveLocalFileSystemUrl` returns

```
{
  "isFile": true,
  "isDirectory": false,
  "name": "enc=fhNPFErrgrEv9o4Q0EfWItmhwQRdSI8diNatIJQGsbDn8UOC\n",
  "fullPath": "/com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc=fhNPFErrgrEv9o4Q0EfWItmhwQRdSI8diNatIJQGsbDn8UOC\n",
  "filesystem": "<FileSystem: content>",
  "nativeURL": "content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3DfhNPFErrgrEv9o4Q0EfWItmhwQRdSI8diNatIJQGsbDn8UOC%0A"
}
```

This is a `DirectoryEntry` as explained in [the documentation of cordova-plugin-file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/) and I can retrieve the blob and the underlying file:

```
{
  "name": "content",
  "localURL": "cdvfile://localhost/content/com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3DfhNPFErrgrEv9o4Q0EfWItmhwQRdSI8diNatIJQGsbDn8UOC%0A",
  "type": "image/jpeg",
  "lastModified": 1524043045078,
  "lastModifiedDate": 1524043045078,
  "size": 1597052,
  "start": 0,
  "end": 1597052
}
```

I am sure the filename is encoded in `enc=fhNPFErrgrEv9o4Q0EfWItmhwQRdSI8diNatIJQGsbDn8UOC` but I cannot manage to decode it.

---

The exact same objects created by an intent from dropbox:

intent object:

```
{
  "action": "android.intent.action.SEND",
  "extras": {
    "android.intent.extra.STREAM": "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u702227782/scratch/IMG_20180116_124017_dropbox.jpg"
  },
  "clipItems": [
    {
      "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u702227782/scratch/IMG_20180116_124017_dropbox.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "type": "image/jpeg",
  "flags": 272629763,
  "component": "ComponentInfo{io.cozy.drive.mobile/io.cozy.drive.mobile.MainActivity}"
}
```

directoryEntry object:

```
{
  "isFile": true,
  "isDirectory": false,
  "name": "IMG_20180116_124017_dropbox.jpg",
  "fullPath": "/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u702227782/scratch/IMG_20180116_124017_dropbox.jpg",
  "filesystem": "<FileSystem: sdcard>",
  "nativeURL": "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u702227782/scratch/IMG_20180116_124017_dropbox.jpg"
}
```

blob/file object:

```
{
  "name": "IMG_20180116_124017_dropbox.jpg",
  "localURL": "cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u702227782/scratch/IMG_20180116_124017_dropbox.jpg",
  "type": "image/jpeg",
  "lastModified": 1524043057000,
  "lastModifiedDate": 1524043057000,
  "size": 1597052,
  "start": 0,
  "end": 1597052
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I update the [cordova-plugin-filepath](https://github.com/hiddentao/cordova-plugin-filepath) to `v1.3.0` and it works like a charm!